# MYSQL novice and subqueries

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
T1      T2
id      id
name    name
t2_id
```

And I want to get all T2 records that aren't linked in T1, how can I do that?
I tried with subqueries, but I'm failed...

```
SELECT * FROM T2
WHERE T1.t2_id NOT IN
(SELECT T2.id FROM T2)
```

Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'T1.t2_id' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'

Comment: I need get all T2 records

Comment: @Goku Closely compare your query with what you want.

Comment: why -1? I'm lost, can't I ask for some help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it backwards:

```
SELECT *
FROM T2
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT t2_id FROM T1)
```

This can also be written as an outer join, and MySQL tends to perform better this way:

```
SELECT T2.*
FROM T2
LEFT JOIN T1 ON T1.t2_id = T2.id
WHERE T1.id IS NULL
```

Make sure you have an index on T1.t2_id for this to perform well.

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there, but note you can only reference columns from tables in the `FROM` clause in your `WHERE` clause.
So you'd probably want to do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   T2
WHERE  T2.id NOT IN
(SELECT T1.t2_id FROM T1)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get all T2 records that aren't linked in T1, how can I do that?

The ones in `T1` are

```
SELECT T1.t2_id FROM T1
```

and the link to `T2` is, of course, done via `T2.id`, so

```
SELECT * FROM T2
WHERE T2.id NOT IN
    (SELECT T1.t2_id FROM T1)
```

seems to be what you want.

If you have a close look, SQL is nearly like everyday's language. Nearly.